# How to parse a generic type through several levels of extends?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following 3 classes:

```
public class MyClass1<T extends MyClass1> {

    private List list = new ArrayList();

    public T add(Object... o) {
        Collections.addAll(this.list, o);
        return (T) this;
    }

    public MyClass2 two() {
        MyClass2 n = new MyClass2();
        add(n);
        return n;
    }
}

public class MyClass2<T extends MyClass2> extends MyClass1<MyClass2> {

    public MyClass3 three() {
        MyClass3 n = new MyClass3();
        add(n);
        return n;
    }
}

public class MyClass3<T extends MyClass3> extends MyClass2<MyClass3> {
}
```

I want to call the methods in a chain. Like this:

```
MyClass1 m1 = new MyClass1();
m1.add(1).add(2).two().add(3).three().add(4);
```

For some reason `add(3)` returns `MyClass1`, where I would have expected it to return `MyClass2`. If I remove `<T extends MyClass2>` from `MyClass2`, `add(3)` returns `MyClass2` as desired, but then `MyClass3` cannot extend `MyClass2` with a type.

How can I make this work, so I can chain all my methods and still use the `add(Object...)` method from all my classes?

**UPDATE:**

The above is clearly an example. What I'm really trying to create here is a simple tool for building MySQL queries. I have a lot of EJB3 entities that already define my table and column names, but need to make a few native queries, because some things just cannot be achieved with EJB-QL. Yet, I don't want to have to specify table and column names more than once in my code, and therefore need a tool that can create a native MySQL query using EJB3 entities. When I use the code I've created, it might look like this:

```
new Query().select().field(MyEntity_.id).field(MyEntity_.name).field(MyOtherEnt_.type);
```

Or:

```
new Query().join().left(MyOtherEnt_.myEntityId);
```

Here I might have a Query object, which specifies some generic MySQL syntax and then extend it. It could be something like this: Query > extended by Select > extended by SubQuery. The whole thing is customized to the specific project I'm working on.

Comment: Did you try to parametrize method calls ?

Comment: This all seems pretty complicated. What are you actually trying to achieve? What is the problem for which this is the solution?

Comment: Hmm than why do you need so many generics extensions? Sounds like a single layer to me. BTW what you are trying to achieve is to create part of framework of eg HIBERNATE size. Check it's sources for such classes like Query and Criteria.Since you are going to reinvent the wheel, I think that you are going to waste a lot of your time.

Comment: If it weren't for this issue, it would be done by tomorrow. I've only got 5, maybe 6, native queries at the moment and everything is designed specifically for the task I'm trying to achieve. It is not like I'm trying to create a extensive, solid framework and release it to the world.

Comment: Still, you are going to have a bad time. I would leave that 6 natives if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

`add(3)` returns `MyClass1` because method `add` is member of class `MyClass1`. You would have to override `add` method in your extending classes in order to return different datatype.

The definition of `MyClass2` should be more or less like that

```
class MyClass2<T extends MyClass2> extends MyClass1<MyClass2> {

    @Override
    public T add(Object... o) {
        super.add(o);
    return (T)this;

    }

    public MyClass3 three() {
        MyClass3 n = new MyClass3();
        add(n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

anyway, I dont know what are you trying to achieve, but IMHO you have took bad approach. Moreover you are not declaring types `T` when you are creating new parametrized objects, so all in all, for compiler and JRE everything here is just of `Object` type.

Comment: Please see my update. Overriding methods definitely works, but I have a lot of methods. If I can avoid overriding them, it would be much preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem is that your're extending *raw* types. Change:

```
public class MyClass1<T extends MyClass1> {
```

to

```
public class MyClass1<T extends MyClass1<T>> {
```

Once you use a raw type, all generic info is stripped from the class.

Similar for the other classes.

Comment: Would you change `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` to `MyClass2<T extends MyClass2<T>>` and `MyClass3<T extends MyClass3<T>>`?

Comment: Definitely. Same applies to them too

Comment: When I do that `m1.add(1).add(2).two().add(3)` returns MyClass1 and `.three()` is not found.

Comment: I've pasted your code into Eclipse, and I'm struggling to understand what your intention is. Maybe you could share...

Comment: I haven't looked into it thoroughly, but it seems like you're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

For now I've decided to make it a little more simple and have `MyClass3` extend `MyClass1` instead of `MyClass2`. If I keep it at "2 levels", it works, so I'll just have to live with the constrain that `MyClass3` cannot extend `MyClass2`, if I want to be able to chain the methods from `MyClass1`. My code then looks like this:

```
public class MyClass1<T extends MyClass1> {

    private List list = new ArrayList();

    public T add(Object... o) {
        Collections.addAll(this.list, o);
        return (T) this;
    }

    public MyClass2 two() {
        MyClass2 n = new MyClass2();
        add(n);
        return n;
    }
}

public class MyClass2 extends MyClass1<MyClass2> {

    public MyClass3 three() {
        MyClass3 n = new MyClass3();
        add(n);
        return n;
    }
}

public class MyClass3 extends MyClass1<MyClass3> {

    public void four() {}
}
```

And I can write:

```
MyClass1 m1 = new MyClass1();
m1.add(1).add(2).two().add(3).add(4).three().add(5).add(6).four();
```